# How to find the document having an array element?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB document as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f3123d8cf714fd9cdb87"),
    "Machine" : "host1",
    "Pools" : [
        "Pool1",
        "Pool2"
    ]
}
```

How do I find all the documents that have pool `Pool1` in "Pools" key in my collection?

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem correct.

```
 db.Resources.find({Pools: {$elemMatch: { "$in", ['Pool1']}}}).pretty()
```

Comment: No need to use `$in` and  `$elemMatch` here. Try this `db.Resources.find({ Pools: 'Pool1' }).pretty()`

Comment: I see, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get what you want.

**Find all records whose Pools' array contains `Pool1`:**

```
db.Resources.find({Pools: 'Pool1'}).pretty()
```

**Find all records whose Pools' array contains the following array elements, the order does not matter**

```
db.Resources.find({Pools: {$all: ['Pool1', ...]}}).pretty()
```

To read more on querying arrays, see this [mongodb post](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)